# error creating reference from interface that extends crudrepo

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoB2a': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches from class org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.detectPotentialMatches(PropertyReferenceException.java:134)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.<init>(PropertyReferenceException.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 12 more

@Component("test")
public class JpaConfig {

@Autowired
daoB2a dao;

public daoB2a getDao() {
    return dao;
}

public void setDao(daoB2a dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}



}

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.company.springdata.daos" />
<context:property-placeholder location="src/main/resources/application.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.drivermanager}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="hbAdapterBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycompany.springdata.entities"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hbAdapterBean"/>
</bean>  

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.springdata.entities"/>



public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext app = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/beans.xml");
    System.out.println("read successfuly");

     //        JpaConfig user = (JpaConfig) app.getBean("test");
     //        System.out.println("user is    "+user);
    //  System.out.println(""+user.getDao().save(new User("dskds", "sds",          "dsds", "dsddskd")));

}
}
```

Comment: If you are hoping for an answer, it would be helpful to ask a question. Also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

make sure you inject daoB2a bean in your xml file 
;

Comment: @Component("test")
public class JpaConfig { }